# I want to show a window (overlay) when I'm hovering over a ListView object

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, hover

I would like to display a kind of window when I move the mouse over a ListView Object. When the mouse leaves the object, the window should close again.

Does anyone have some tips for me?

Of course that did not work that way. In addition, the window should go to the mouse and not somewhere.

Test:

```
private void ListViewBilling_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        _billingInfoWindow = new BillingInfoWindow();
        _billingInfoWindow.ShowDialog();
}


private void ListViewBilling_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        _billingInfoWindow.Close();
}
```

The window closes and opens continuously.

How do I get a window (popup) to be displayed only when the mouse is moved over a ListView object? Not everywhere in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ToolTip or Popup controls. Details here:

[WPF ToolTips - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip?view=netframework-4.8)

[WPF Popups - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview)

Understand the differences and choose the best you need. Main differences are:

- ToolTips should not be hoverable, just some extra information
- Popups are separate windows, they can get custom, clickable items (eg. buttons)

Popups can be opened on hover as well.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the dialog box opens which causes the mouse to leave the billing window which causes the dialog box to close.  Then the mouse re-enters the billing window which opens the dialog box, etc., etc.  This is causing the loop you are seeing.

I suggest that you adjust and have the dialog box close when the mouse leaves the dialog box.

Comment: How do I get a window (popup) to be displayed only when the mouse is moved over a ListView object? Not everywhere in the ListView. I want to display the information of the ListView Objects in the popup, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution looks like this:

```
    private void Show_PopupBillingPreview(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var listViewItem = e.Source as ListViewItem;
        var billing = listViewItem?.Content as Billing;
        PuBillingPreviewTitle.Text = billing?.BillingId.ToString();
        PuBillingPreview.PlacementTarget = listViewItem;
        PuBillingPreview.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint;

        PuBillingPreview.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Hide_PopupBillingPreview(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PuBillingPreview.IsOpen)
            PuBillingPreview.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Now I have the problem that I have a flicker when the popup window appears directly under the mouse.